# Use always same eslint config and override

Tags: eslint, config

Ive crated an ESLint config on C:User. The problem is that sometimes I have a specific config file on the specific projects.
What I want to do is ignore the config file on the specific project (without editing any on the project config file) and always use the one on C:User

```
.
├── .eslintrc.js
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── projects
    └── project_01
        └── some_module
            ├── .eslintrc.js
            ├── node_modules
            ├── package-lock.json
            └── package.json
    └── project_02
        └── some_module
            ├── .eslintrc.js
            ├── node_modules
            ├── package-lock.json
            └── package.json
```

I want to use always the same ESLint config file for every project